# Как найти индекс строк по списку значений?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, индексация

Задача следующая: есть DataFrame, допустим, следующий:

| indx | Book | Author | tax_genre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Dubrovski | Pushkin | Novel |
| 1 | Vanka | Chehov | Tail |
| 2 | O lubvi | Chehov | Tail |
| 3 | O lubvi | Chehov | Tail |
| 4 | O lubvi | Chehov | Tail |
| 5 | Karamazovi | Dostoevski | Novel |

Имеется список `['O lubvi', 'Chehov', 'Tail']`. Необходимо получить по фрейму список с индексами строк, в которых присутствуют все эти значения, т.е. `[2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: И что вы уже сами пробовали сделать? Есть вариант в лоб же проверять каждый из столбцов на совпадение, потом совместить условия

Comment: @CrazyElf Зря вы не добавили - "только не циклом", а то сейчас начнется :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Еще один вариант решения:

```
search_vals = ['O lubvi', 'Chehov', 'Tail']

qry = " and ".join(f"{f}=='{v}'" for f,v in zip(df.columns, search_vals))

res = df.query(qry).index.to_list()
```

результат:

```
In [24]: res
Out[24]: [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: спасибо! отличное гибкое решение, то что нужно

Answer (score 4):

В общем, всё просто. Можно вот прямо сравнивать всем списком:

```
print(list(df.loc[(df[['Book', 'Author', 'tax genre']] == ['O lubvi', 'Chehov', 'Tail']).all(axis=1)].index))
```

Вывод:

```
[2, 3, 4]
```